# Adding markers/colors in an IOS app that is using apple maps violates the license?

Tags: licensing

I want to use the apple maps for a ios application and saw this in license: (c) reproduce, modify, translate, or create derivative works of the Service or any portion thereof; https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/maps/terms-en.html

1.Integrating maps and putting multiple CUSTOM markers will violate the license?

2.How about the modifying map colors, will it violate the license?

3.Is there a requests per day/month usage limit?

I cannot understand what violates the license and what doesn't. Thanks in advance for response

Comment: Part (c), which you are quoting, is talking about copying or modifying the service itself. If you use the Apple Maps API to apply the customizations you want, that is not modifying the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point 3: The T&C's don't allow you to do mass downloads, scraping the information found, and so on. I can't find a limit to the number of requests, and considering that millions of people use the service to drive through the country, you shouldn't be able to do anything noticable through normal use.